# Run a function as today's date

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-functions

I have a query below that calls on a stored function.  In the function you will see I need to declare a start date (@startdate) and an end date (@End date).  These queries will be used inside a C# program that will run via windows task scheduler.  The idea of this is to pull reports for the sales info each day and auto email it at night as part of nightly reports.  Because of this I will need to assign @startdate to "today's" date.  For example if the program is auto run today, I need sales info for 1/29/13 00:00 through 1/29/13 23:00.  Tomorrow when it's run I'll need sales infor for 1/30/13 00:00 through 1/30/13 23:00.  Etc.  I am using the dateadd datediff in my other queries for the report, however this is the only query referencing a stored function.  How would I accomplish the same thing in a stored function?

Here is my query calling a Stored Function:

```
SELECT
  SUM(QTY) AS Discounts
FROM
  dbo.fFinancialDataFull('Date Range Report', @startdate , @enddate, '1', '1', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1') AS fFinancialDataFull_1
WHERE
  (ReportCategoryID = 62)) AS unlimitedtbl
```

Comment: I fail to see where you are passing any date parameter. Can you please clarify.

Comment: I changed it to show the parameter

Comment: You want startdate and enddate to be for example '2013-01-29 00:00:00' resp '2013-01-29 23:59:59' automatically?

Comment: It looks like they want records where Tickets.dtCreated occurred today. Another way you could do this is simply to convert the DateTime value of each to a Date and check equality. It's probably easier than doing the DateAdd/DateDiff method. Convert(Date,Tickets.dtCreated) = Convert(Date,GetDate())

Comment: @asken In this example yes.  But tomorrow I will want 1/30, the next day 1/31 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to tell if you want to generate the date before your current query or inside of the function.

If you want to do it before you call the function. You can easily use:

```
DECLARE @startdate AS DATETIME;
DECLARE @endDate AS DATETIME;

--- code that will work on any version of SQL Server
SET @startdate = DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
SET @enddate = DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) 
                            + CAST('23:59:59' as datetime)

-- SQL Server 2008+ code with DATE datatype
SET @startdate = CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) as datetime);
SET @enddate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) + CAST('23:59:59' as datetime);

SELECT SUM(QTY) AS Discounts
FROM dbo.fFinancialDataFull('Date Range Report', @startdate , @enddate, '1', '1',
                             'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', '1', '1', 
                               '1', '1', '1') AS fFinancialDataFull_1
WHERE ReportCategoryID = 62
```

The start date will be at midnight and the end date will be the current date minus one second. (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8583))

If you are looking for a way to easily generate today's date at midnight and then an enddate of today's date with the time `23:59:59`, then you could create a [`Table-Valued Function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

This type of function can return both the `startdate` and `enddate` based on a value that you pass in.

If it is possible, then I would alter your current function to accept one date parameter, then inside of that function you can call a new function that will return the dates.

The new function will be similar to this:

```
create function dbo.GetStartEndDates
(
    -- pass in the date
    @dt datetime
)
RETURNS @dates table
(
    StartDate datetime,
    EndDate datetime
) 
AS
BEGIN
    insert into @dates
    select CAST(CAST(@dt AS DATE) as datetime) startdate,  -- returns yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000
        CAST(@dt AS DATE) + CAST('23:59:59' as datetime) enddate -- returns yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59.000

    return
END
```

Then your current function would include:

```
alter function dbo.fFinancialDataFull
(
   --your list of parameters
   --replace the start/end date with
   @dateValue datetime
)
returns table...
as
begin
   select *
   from yourtable
   cross apply dbo.GetStartEndDates(@dateValue) d -- this will return both start/end date
end
```

You could then use the start/end date in the rest of your query.

When you are calling your current function you would pass in `getdate()` or whatever datetime as the :

```
select *
from dbo.fFinancialDataFull(param1, param2, getdate(), etc, etc).
```

Comment: I cannot add procedures, and I cannot alter functions.  It's a synced database so my changes will be overwritten.

Comment: @Shmewnix then you would have to use the code in my first part of the answer that gets the `@startdate` and `@enddate` prior to your function call.

Comment: DATE is not a defined system type.

Comment: @Shmewnix you tagged as sql server 2008?  What version of sql server?

Comment: 2008 and 2005. depends on the location.

Comment: @Shmewnix Ahh, well SQL Server 2008 has a `date` datatype. I edited my code with a version that will work on both

Comment: It works on the 2008 server.  What about 2005?  Is there a function like "DATE" in 2005 that will work?

Comment: I have to wait to award the bounty (22hours), but as soon as the time passes, I'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the date you can use the following SQL instead of a function:

```
 CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),1) AS DATETIME)
```

Substituting `1` with whatever format you want to work with from the chart on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Store this code into a variable and that should do it.  I use this exact code in many of my SSIS packages and store it to a variable for use in output naming and logging. +1

Comment: I need to call the Function within the function is the startdate and enddate.  So I need to define the startdate and enddate as today's date.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want todays date without the time aspect simply:

```
Convert(Date,GetDate())
```

You can do the same to any other DateTime value and check equality and it will be true if they occurred at any point on the same day.